# Transfer always empty in php curl

Tags: php, curl

I've never worked with curl before so I'm trying to just set up something basic: query google.com and write it. This is what I have:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if ($curl_errno > 0) {
  echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
} else {
  if(empty($buffer)) {
    echo "No data received.";
  } else {
    echo "Data received: $buffer\n";
  }
}

?>
```

However, it's returning "No data received" every single time.

This is in Kubuntu 11.04 x64 with PHP version 5.3.5 and cURL version 7.21.3.

Comment: You're using `$curl_handle` for the call but `$ch` for everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing your variable names `$ch` and `$curl_handle`. You can't do this. Be consistent (`$ch` is pretty standard):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$buffer = curl_exec($ch); // Changed variable name here
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch); // Removed duplicate line here
curl_close($ch); // Changed variable name here

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was mixing from several examples and didn't notice that they were using different variable names... that's what I get for working at 4 am...

Answer (score 0):

Fix this

```
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

to

```
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
```

and also it should be,

```
curl_close($ch)
```

not $curl_handle. Btw, closing curl is not really necessary for what ur doing. But its a good practice nevertheless.